# Formula isn't working in computed column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server management studio. I have a column named salary. I want another computed column based on salary: `(salary *20%+salary)/85` but I don't get the result.

I tried putting the formula in computed column specification tab under properties tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following to calculate the value:

```
(salary * 1.2) / 85
```

See a [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6079)

Answer (score 2):

That is an invalid SQL computation.

Instead of multiplying by percentage, divide by 100 and multiply by the percentage value:

```
(((salary/100)*20)+salary)/85
```